# Methods .text() and .html() in jQuery strip trailing whitespace in IE7?

Tags: jquery, string, insert, whitespace, internet-explorer-7

I'm using jQuery to insert text inside a HTML tag. The HTML code looks like this:

```
<h5>Do you want to send a message to <span id='firstName'></span> right now?</h5>
```

The jQuery code for inserting the text inside the span tag looks like this:

```
var myFirstName = "Thomas";
$("h5 span.firstName").html(myFirstName);
```

When I run this code in Firefox, Chrome, Safari or IE8 the result is this:

```
<h5>Do you want to send a message to <span id='firstName'>Thomas</span> right now?</h5>
```

But in Internet Explorer 7, the result is this:

```
<h5>Do you want to send a message to <span id='firstName'>Thomas</span>right now?</h5>
```

The trailing white space after the span tag is stripped resulting in a text on-screen that reads: "**Do you want to send a message to Thomasright now?**".

I've tried using both .html() and .text() but there is no difference in the result.

Is there a way to fix this bug? Is it a known bug in jQuery/IE7?

Thanks in advance!

/Thomas Kahn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

making `<span id='firstName'></span>` to `<span id='firstName'>&nbsp;</span>` will fixed the problem. ^^

## [simple demo page](http://jsfiddle.net/reigel/YCdGW/)

<sup>^ open this on IE 7</sup>

Comment: I have the same problem, but this solution doesn't help me because my content all needs to be visible on load, even when the span contains nothing. E.g. `we'll give you <span></span> points when` needs to not show an extra space.  The sentence makes sense even before the # of points is specified, and it simply becomes more specific when the span contains an amount of points.  So I need to somehow fix the jquery IE7 bug without adding `&nbsp;`, and I haven't found a solution that applies to my case.

Answer (score 2):

That is strange but you can do this:

```
var myFirstName = "Thomas&nbsp;";
$("h5 span.firstName").html(myFirstName);
```

Comment: This answer seemed to work for me, even for the case I described in my comment above (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4497361/methods-text-and-html-in-jquery-strip-trailing-whitespace-in-ie7#comment17062549_4497488).